# [_UILayoutGuide isDescendantOfView:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to dismiss a modally presented view with dismissViewControllerAnimated causes a BAD_ACCESS error. Using zombies it is revealed that "[_UILayoutGuide isDescendantOfView:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1741b9980". The error disappears if I use [self.removeFromSuperView] but causes a black flickering because the removal happens before the modal dismiss animation completes. What is wrong? I tried to ise unwind segues to do this automatically but I'm not sure how to make unwind to work on a modal and go to the caller view.

update:

Code that calls the modal:

```
- (void)openCart {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openCart" sender:self];
}
```

(openCart is a custom modal segue)

Code that tries to dismiss the modal (like a cancel button)

```
- (IBAction)closeCart:(id)sender {  
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have managed to solve the "flickering" issue by changing the completion handler and addig a [self.view removeFromSuperView] there, but I still don't understand why it isn't working without the remove and I still want to know if a custom unwind segue could do the same.

Comment: Please include the code you're using which causes this.

Comment: are you working with sizeClasses?

Comment: I'm having nearly same issue. It happens while I pop current VC. I'm using sizeClass. but this happens 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: Okay Now I'm facing this issue very frequently, like 6/10.

Comment: Have you checked to see that your VC is not set to "Freeform" in Simulated Metrics? I just corrected a dismissal zombie crash with the same message by resetting the size of the VC involved to "Inferred."