# crash on EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on dismiss view controller in WebRTC library

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am using webRTC framework for audio call in my application. After dismissing call view controller I am getting the following error on App delegate.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Following is the screenshot of xcode

[image]

Following is the stack trace

```
CallViewController.__ivar_destroyer:
0x101d2c780 <+0>:    pushq  %rbp
0x101d2c781 <+1>:    movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x101d2c784 <+4>:    subq   $0x20, %rsp
0x101d2c788 <+8>:    movq   %rdi, %rax
0x101d2c78b <+11>:   movq   %rax, -0x8(%rbp)
0x101d2c78f <+15>:   movq   0x16dfb02(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.(ws in _024208FCD932FF59905765BE8E3FA1C3) : SwiftWebSocket.WebSocket
0x101d2c796 <+22>:   movq   (%rdi,%rax), %rax
0x101d2c79a <+26>:   movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
0x101d2c79e <+30>:   movq   %rax, %rdi
0x101d2c7a1 <+33>:   movq   %rsi, -0x18(%rbp)
0x101d2c7a5 <+37>:   callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c7aa <+42>:   movq   0x16defcf(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reachability : __ObjC.Reachability
0x101d2c7b1 <+49>:   movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c7b5 <+53>:   movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c7b9 <+57>:   callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c7be <+62>:   movq   0x16defc3(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnBack : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2c7c5 <+69>:   movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c7c9 <+73>:   movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c7cd <+77>:   callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c7d2 <+82>:   movq   0x16defb7(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblTopicWait : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2c7d9 <+89>:   movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c7dd <+93>:   movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c7e1 <+97>:   callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c7e6 <+102>:  movq   0x16defab(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblMessageWait : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2c7ed <+109>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c7f1 <+113>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c7f5 <+117>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c7fa <+122>:  movq   0x16def9f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgWait : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2c801 <+129>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c805 <+133>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c809 <+137>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c80e <+142>:  movq   0x16def93(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewWaiting : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2c815 <+149>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c819 <+153>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c81d <+157>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c822 <+162>:  movq   0x16def87(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewBeforeCall : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2c829 <+169>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c82d <+173>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c831 <+177>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c836 <+182>:  movq   0x16def7b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgAlpha : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2c83d <+189>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c841 <+193>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c845 <+197>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c84a <+202>:  movq   0x16def6f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblTopic : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2c851 <+209>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c855 <+213>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c859 <+217>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c85e <+222>:  movq   0x16def63(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblTime : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2c865 <+229>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c869 <+233>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c86d <+237>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c872 <+242>:  movq   0x16def57(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnHangup : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2c879 <+249>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c87d <+253>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c881 <+257>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c886 <+262>:  movq   0x16def4b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnMicrophone : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2c88d <+269>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c891 <+273>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c895 <+277>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c89a <+282>:  movq   0x16def3f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnSpeaker : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2c8a1 <+289>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c8a5 <+293>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c8a9 <+297>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c8ae <+302>:  movq   0x16def33(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnNext : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2c8b5 <+309>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c8b9 <+313>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c8bd <+317>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c8c2 <+322>:  movq   0x16def27(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.stackViewCalls : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIStackView>
0x101d2c8c9 <+329>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c8cd <+333>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c8d1 <+337>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c8d6 <+342>:  movq   0x16def1b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewCall1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2c8dd <+349>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c8e1 <+353>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c8e5 <+357>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c8ea <+362>:  movq   0x16def0f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewCall2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2c8f1 <+369>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c8f5 <+373>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c8f9 <+377>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c8fe <+382>:  movq   0x16def03(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewCall3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2c905 <+389>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c909 <+393>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c90d <+397>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c912 <+402>:  movq   0x16deef7(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewCall4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2c919 <+409>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c91d <+413>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c921 <+417>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c926 <+422>:  movq   0x16deeeb(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.webv1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIWebView>
0x101d2c92d <+429>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c931 <+433>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c935 <+437>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c93a <+442>:  movq   0x16deedf(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.webv2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIWebView>
0x101d2c941 <+449>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c945 <+453>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c949 <+457>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c94e <+462>:  movq   0x16deed3(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.webv3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIWebView>
0x101d2c955 <+469>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c959 <+473>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c95d <+477>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c962 <+482>:  movq   0x16deec7(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.webv4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIWebView>
0x101d2c969 <+489>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c96d <+493>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c971 <+497>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c976 <+502>:  movq   0x16deebb(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgAvatar1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2c97d <+509>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c981 <+513>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c985 <+517>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c98a <+522>:  movq   0x16deeaf(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblName1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2c991 <+529>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c995 <+533>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c999 <+537>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c99e <+542>:  movq   0x16deea3(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgLocation1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2c9a5 <+549>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c9a9 <+553>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c9ad <+557>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c9b2 <+562>:  movq   0x16dee97(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblCountry1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2c9b9 <+569>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c9bd <+573>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c9c1 <+577>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c9c6 <+582>:  movq   0x16dee8b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2c9cd <+589>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c9d1 <+593>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c9d5 <+597>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c9da <+602>:  movq   0x16dee7f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg11 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2c9e1 <+609>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c9e5 <+613>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c9e9 <+617>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2c9ee <+622>:  movq   0x16dee73(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgReport1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2c9f5 <+629>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2c9f9 <+633>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2c9fd <+637>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca02 <+642>:  movq   0x16dee67(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblReport1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2ca09 <+649>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca0d <+653>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca11 <+657>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca16 <+662>:  movq   0x16dee5b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgAvatar2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2ca1d <+669>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca21 <+673>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca25 <+677>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca2a <+682>:  movq   0x16dee4f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblName2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2ca31 <+689>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca35 <+693>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca39 <+697>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca3e <+702>:  movq   0x16dee43(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgLocation2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2ca45 <+709>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca49 <+713>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca4d <+717>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca52 <+722>:  movq   0x16dee37(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblCountry2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2ca59 <+729>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca5d <+733>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca61 <+737>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca66 <+742>:  movq   0x16dee2b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnReport2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2ca6d <+749>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca71 <+753>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca75 <+757>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca7a <+762>:  movq   0x16dee1f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2ca81 <+769>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca85 <+773>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca89 <+777>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ca8e <+782>:  movq   0x16dee13(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg22 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2ca95 <+789>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ca99 <+793>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ca9d <+797>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2caa2 <+802>:  movq   0x16dee07(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgReport2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2caa9 <+809>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2caad <+813>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cab1 <+817>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cab6 <+822>:  movq   0x16dedfb(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblReport2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2cabd <+829>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cac1 <+833>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cac5 <+837>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2caca <+842>:  movq   0x16dedef(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgAvatar3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cad1 <+849>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cad5 <+853>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cad9 <+857>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cade <+862>:  movq   0x16dede3(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblName3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2cae5 <+869>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cae9 <+873>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2caed <+877>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2caf2 <+882>:  movq   0x16dedd7(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgLocation3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2caf9 <+889>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cafd <+893>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb01 <+897>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb06 <+902>:  movq   0x16dedcb(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblCountry3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2cb0d <+909>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb11 <+913>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb15 <+917>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb1a <+922>:  movq   0x16dedbf(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnReport3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2cb21 <+929>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb25 <+933>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb29 <+937>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb2e <+942>:  movq   0x16dedb3(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cb35 <+949>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb39 <+953>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb3d <+957>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb42 <+962>:  movq   0x16deda7(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg33 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cb49 <+969>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb4d <+973>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb51 <+977>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb56 <+982>:  movq   0x16ded9b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgReport3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cb5d <+989>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb61 <+993>:  movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb65 <+997>:  callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb6a <+1002>: movq   0x16ded8f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblReport3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2cb71 <+1009>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb75 <+1013>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb79 <+1017>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb7e <+1022>: movq   0x16ded83(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgAvatar4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cb85 <+1029>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb89 <+1033>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cb8d <+1037>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cb92 <+1042>: movq   0x16ded77(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblName4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2cb99 <+1049>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cb9d <+1053>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cba1 <+1057>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cba6 <+1062>: movq   0x16ded6b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgLocation4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cbad <+1069>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cbb1 <+1073>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cbb5 <+1077>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cbba <+1082>: movq   0x16ded5f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblCountry4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2cbc1 <+1089>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cbc5 <+1093>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cbc9 <+1097>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cbce <+1102>: movq   0x16ded53(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.btnReport4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIButton>
0x101d2cbd5 <+1109>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cbd9 <+1113>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cbdd <+1117>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cbe2 <+1122>: movq   0x16ded47(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cbe9 <+1129>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cbed <+1133>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cbf1 <+1137>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cbf6 <+1142>: movq   0x16ded3b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgBg44 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cbfd <+1149>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc01 <+1153>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc05 <+1157>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc0a <+1162>: movq   0x16ded2f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.imgReport4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIImageView>
0x101d2cc11 <+1169>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc15 <+1173>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc19 <+1177>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc1e <+1182>: movq   0x16ded23(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.lblReport4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UILabel>
0x101d2cc25 <+1189>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc29 <+1193>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc2d <+1197>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc32 <+1202>: movq   0x16ded17(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewReport1 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cc39 <+1209>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc3d <+1213>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc41 <+1217>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc46 <+1222>: movq   0x16ded0b(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar11 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cc4d <+1229>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc51 <+1233>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc55 <+1237>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc5a <+1242>: movq   0x16decff(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar12 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cc61 <+1249>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc65 <+1253>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc69 <+1257>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc6e <+1262>: movq   0x16decf3(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar13 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cc75 <+1269>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc79 <+1273>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc7d <+1277>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc82 <+1282>: movq   0x16dece7(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewReport2 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cc89 <+1289>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cc8d <+1293>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cc91 <+1297>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cc96 <+1302>: movq   0x16decdb(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar21 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cc9d <+1309>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cca1 <+1313>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cca5 <+1317>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ccaa <+1322>: movq   0x16deccf(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar22 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2ccb1 <+1329>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ccb5 <+1333>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ccb9 <+1337>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ccbe <+1342>: movq   0x16decc3(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar23 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2ccc5 <+1349>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ccc9 <+1353>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cccd <+1357>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ccd2 <+1362>: movq   0x16decb7(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewReport3 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2ccd9 <+1369>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ccdd <+1373>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cce1 <+1377>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cce6 <+1382>: movq   0x16decab(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar31 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cced <+1389>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2ccf1 <+1393>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2ccf5 <+1397>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2ccfa <+1402>: movq   0x16dec9f(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar32 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cd01 <+1409>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cd05 <+1413>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cd09 <+1417>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cd0e <+1422>: movq   0x16dec93(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.reportBar33 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cd15 <+1429>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cd19 <+1433>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cd1d <+1437>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x101d2cd22 <+1442>: movq   0x16dec87(%rip), %rax     ; direct field offset for GopChat.CallViewController.viewReport4 : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<__ObjC.UIView>
0x101d2cd29 <+1449>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x101d2cd2d <+1453>: movq   (%rsi,%rax), %rdi
0x101d2cd31 <+1457>: callq  0x102b63130               ; symbol stub
```

I have tried **NSZombie** but could not find anything. I shall be thankful for help.

When I comment the following lines in viewDidLoad() there is no crash

```
localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.audioTrack(withTrackId: uuid!)
mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.mediaStream(withStreamId: LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID)
mediaStream.addAudioTrack(localAudioTrack)
```

Here is the declaration of these variables

```
private var mediaStream: RTCMediaStream!
private var localAudioTrack: RTCAudioTrack!
private var dataChannel: RTCDataChannel!
```

Comment: Please post the console output

Comment: There is no error message in console.

Comment: Add Exception Breakpoint and try!!!:)

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya I have already added exception breakpoint.

Comment: In which line breakpoint stopping?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya it is stopping on app delegate. It is not stopping on any line in code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334284/exc-bad-access-crash-upon-dismissing-uiviewcontroller

Comment: My error is not due to Layout. It is on deallocation of the view controller. I think on deallocation it is accessing objects that are not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the mediaStream and localAudioTrack variables weak. This will create weak pointers to them and if no objects are referring to them any more they get released from the stack. Also weak will make them possible to become nil once released.

Comment: Which code should I share? The whole class is very lengthy. May cross character limit of SO.

Comment: Definitely not the whole class :) I am speculating that you have some completion handlers/closures that run asynchronously and when you dismiss they come back and try to refer to self (which is destroyed by that time) so in these cases I use [weak self] in my closure that makes self optional and won't crash the app if it no longer exists. If can find any cases of these closures you could post them or just try the weak self there.

Comment: I have posted a function onOffer which is called asynchronously. Can you please tell me how can I add [weak self] in it? Thanks again.

Comment: SO you don't add weak self to the function but to the closure that calls onOffer. Check where it is being called from, e.g. SomeClass.somefunction(completion: {  self.onOffer() })

Comment: Do you mean (for example) DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.setCallerHidden(view1: self.viewCall2, reason: reason, name: self.lblName2.text ?? "No name")
                            self.counter2 = 0
                    }                   TO                   DispatchQueue.main.async
                        { [weak self] in
                            self?.setCallerHidden(view1: (self?.viewCall2)!, reason: reason, name: self?.lblName2.text ?? "No name")
                            self?.counter2 = 0
                    }

Comment: That's it. This will only allow to call members of self if self is .some (so when self has a value).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160580/discussion-between-andras-m-and-fawad-masud).